# No field to add subscription status url under app information in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My app has a renewable subscription, and I want to subscribe to any change in subscription status(a url in my server should get hit). Apparently, we can do that by setting URL to **Subscription status URL** in iTunes under app information section. However, I can not see that field at all.

Below is my view.

[image]

Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

Add at least one auto-renewable subscription to the new app version:

[image]

Once that is done, a new field "Subscription status URL" should appear in the app info section:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was confused by this too. Here's an update of where to find it. General > App Information > App Store Server Notifications (at the bottom of the page)

[image]